# iOS equivalent solution of Android's WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams

Tags: ios, input, file-upload, wkwebview, webchromeclient

Are there any ways of adding/setting an image/video/audio file from an iOS app into the  tag of wkwebview's web page?

In android, this can be done by WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams class to save files picked from device into the mobile web page.

But how we can achieve this in iOS?

Comment: same problem here, none solutions found yet. Did you found some clue?

Comment: Same issue, @Vivek did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: Looking for solution of similar usecase